# output the value of var Status in html

Tags: jsp, foreach

I don't have much experience with jsp so this may seem like a silly question, but how do you output the value of `varStatus` in a forEach loop?

here is the loop:

```
<ul class="local-navigation">
    <c:forEach var="tabResource" items="${viewModel.navTabResources}" varStatus="myIndex">
        <sling:include resource="${ tabResource }" resourceType="navigation/tab/render" />
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

and in the included file I am calling varStatus="myIndex" like so:

```
<a href="#" data-target=".navList-${myIndex.count}" <c:choose>
```

but when I build, the rendered html shows no value from the varStatus variable(like this):

```
<a href="#" data-visibility-target=".navList-">...</a>
```

What am I doing wrong here? or a better question: how do I pass the varStatus variable to the scope of the included file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before your `<include>`, set your `varStatus` value into the `request` scope to make it available to the included JSP resource.

```
<c:forEach var="tabResource" items="${viewModel.navTabResources}" varStatus="myIndex">
   <c:set var="loopIndex" value="${myIndex}" scope="request" />
   <sling:include resource="${tabResource}" resourceType="navigation/tab/render" />
</c:forEach>
```

Now this would perfectly work out with a `<jsp:include>` as the `request` and `response` objects are passed to it and the JSP `${EL}` syntax to retrieve the value in the included resource with `${loopIndex}` would also work.

But, I'm not sure if the `<sling:include>` custom tag has been written to support all this. If it doesn't work, you would need to modify it to take up another attribute on the same lines as `resource` to pass the `varStatus` value as well.

```
<sling:include resource="${tabResource}" loopIndex="${varStatus}" resourceType=... />
```